# Jquery selector for input:checkbox unchecked and with ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I check other answer for similar problem, so either with this question:

Need select all Input:Checkbox from a Form but identifying his ID.

I try with: `$( "input:checkbox[id^='ingr_']" )` and run perfect for "Checked" elements. So the unchecked elements, jquery said to use :not(:checked). Put this on the code then obtain nothing (checked or unchecked).

This is my sample code running on fiddle: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mastercafe/d6o73avf/5/)

Comment: How about this `$( "input[id^='ingr_']:checkbox")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem come from serializeArray() method. 
It removes unchecked checkbox.

https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

If you made ​​a console.log of 
`$ ('input:checkbox[id^='comp_']:not(:checked)')` , it works well.

Comment: Thanks, efectively serialize remove unchecked fields. How to emulate serializeArray to use this selection?

Comment: The solution was simply eliminate serializeArray because next line construct the string with selector

Answer (score 0):

This code will count all unchecked checkboxes:

```
var countUnChecked = function() {
    var n = $('input:checkbox:not(":checked")').length
    alert( n + " Unchecked." );
};
```